# plain text email for Cognito verification code

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is there a way to send Cognito verification email as plain text email?

Some of our customers use MMS email for Cognito registration. They use the app **Message** on iPhone to read those emails. After registration, the email verification comes but shows up on the Message as an HTML attachment, which needs a tap to open up the email content.

We want the content to show up nicely as an bubble-message, which can be done if the email is sent in plain text not HTML. I tried adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />` to the message customizations but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom sender has solved my problem
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html

Note that this trigger is not available in the console, so you must use `update-user-pool` api call to add it.

One important thing about this api is noted in the document: `If you don't provide a value for an attribute, it will be set to the default value.` . I wasted a lot of time to debug just to find out that some settings had been changed due to this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can, yes.

1. Setup the Cognito Custom Message Trigger to call a lambda (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html)
2. Create a lambda script that sends an email using AWS SES. Using SES you can specify separate HTML and TEXT parts of the message (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html)